# xampp with asp (not aspx)

Tags: asp-classic, xampp

is it possible to use xampp (apache 2) with asp (it works with aspx, but i want to use "normal" asp). With kind regard, JSMB

Answer (score 2):

Thanks, I "solved" this with using quickwebserver. http://www.pablosoftwaresolutions.com/
Now I can use classic ASP with XP home edition (and of course it's not free :-(   ;-))

Answer (score 1):

From [a slightly dated page](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/faq-xampp-windows.html#asp):

> **Do Microsoft Activer Server Pages (ASP) work with XAMPP?**
>
> No! And Perl:ASP in the Perl Add-on is not the same! Unfortunately no free implementation for the Apache is available.

Edit: However it may be possible to run mod_proxy on Apache. mod_proxy is a reverse proxy which should allow you to transparently relay requests to IIS. I haven't done this with either Apache *or* IIS, so I can't advise you here.

Answer (score 0):

You mean "Classic ASP"? As far as I know, ASP for windows is only possible with IIS. For linux (apache) it was possible with chillisoft and the like, but it's probably not free, nor available anymore...